# How to upload split application binary at Play Store

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, apk-expansion-files

My game APK file size increased by 100mb so I require to split it. So now I have two files with .apk and .obb extension. But at play store there is no way exist to upload OBB file.

Here is my play store account screenshot:

[image]

I have uploaded APK file but where to upload OBB file??

**EDIT:**
After uploading APK file, I can't able to get any option for uploading expansion file. I get this kind of overview about uploaded file.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After uploading your APK file, you should see something like this:

[image]

Have a look at [Add or test APK expansion files](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2481797?hl=en-GB):

> You can upload new or add existing expansion files to APKs in a draft
>   release.
>
> 1. Go to your Play Console.
> 2. Select your app.
> 3. On the left menu, click Release management > App releases.
> 4. Next to the release type you want to update, select Manage.
> 5. Drop or select your app's APK file.
> 6. You'll see a list of APKs that are associated with your release. Next
>      to the relevant version code, select the add icon .
> 7. Choose whether you want to upload a new file or attach an existing
>      expansion file.
>
>    - If the APK hasn't been published yet, you can change or remove an
>        expansion file by selecting another file or No expansion file. You
>        can't remove expansion files from an existing release.
> 8. Select Save.

Read more: [Deploying an Android app in Google Play](https://help.twixlmedia.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000790645-Deploying-an-Android-app-in-Google-Play)

Comment: Please sir check my question edit, there is no option exist for expansion file upload.

Comment: Thank you sir for your perfect help :)

Comment: This is a very helpful answer

Answer (score 3):

Umair's answer is correct and you can see that. One important caveat is you can only add an expansion file (with the little + button) to an APK *that has never been released*. If you follow the instructions in Umair's answer with a new APK (but before publishing) you should see the button on the App Releases page.

Comment: Yes I went through each step carefully and find the exact button.